# HTML and CSS for Paged Printing from Non-Print User Agents

Tags: css, google-chrome, browser, printing

CSS has features specifically to support printing, designed for user agents intended for printing, the best known of which is probably Prince. Alas, browsers aren't such user agents, and Prince is expensive ($500 for the desktop version).

So I started looking into a closely-related problem: Whether it would be possible to produce properly paginated and formatted output using the print feature of a browser (Chrome, in my case), where the user agent (the browser) outputs to the screen, not to a printer, although it is able to print the contents of the browser window. (That's not the same thing as being a user agent for printing.) As anyone who's tried it finds out, Chrome (and probably other browsers) doesn't support the CSS `@page` rule. That means there's no practical way to, for example, distinguish between left and right pages, but in my case that didn't matter.

All I needed was:

- Paginated output, and
- Precise control over placement on the printed page.

Normally, when you print a browser page exact formatting isn't important. Think of a shipping label, a boarding pass, or notes for a meeting. But, in my case, the printed page is the critical part, and the browser rendition is merely a preview. Specifically, I was trying to prepare a PDF for a photo book for uploading to MagCloud, an on-demand magazine printing service (owned by Blurb, the book-printing people).

(Many apps, like Lightroom, have book layout capabilities, but for reasons not germane to this post I couldn't use any of them.)

So my question, which I'm also going to answer is: What's a simple way to produce precise printed output from a browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that, while Chrome doesn't support `@page`, it does support the `page-break-before` style. So, to get paginated printed output, all you have to do is something like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang=en>
<head>
    <meta charset=utf-8>
    <title></title>
    <style>
        * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        .page {
            position: relative;
            page-break-before: always;
            width: 5.5in;
            height: 8.5in;
        }
        .inner {
            position: relative;
            top: .25in;
            left: .25in;
            width: 5in;
            height: 8in;
            border: 1px solid blue;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class=page>
        <div class=inner>
            <p>This is page one.
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class=page>
        <div class=inner>
            <p>This is page two.
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Note that I'm using inches instead of pixels, thus neatly avoiding the issue of the resolution of the printed page in pixels. (It happens to be 96, but I'm not using that fact, and it might be different on different systems anyway.) Millimeters would work as well.

Here's how it looked in my browser:

[image: Two pages in browser]

I found that the built-in Windows 10 PDF print driver isn't accurate, producing pages that don't reflect the sizes I set in CSS. The free CutePDF Writer, however, is dead on, as is Mac OS X.

Here's the PDF in Acrobat Reader:

[image]

As you can see, it's perfect. All you have to do is lay out your content inside the `<div class=inner>` and you're set. If you want a full-page bleed, such as for a book-cover photo, put the content directly in the `<div class=page>`.

In my application I generated the actual HTML from a PHP program, but this static HTML illustrates the important concepts.